# Media Library Categories

Tags: categories, theme-development, media-library

I am using the following to assign categories to my WordPress Media Library (in `functions.php`):

```
function wptp_add_categories_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'wptp_add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

Each Media Library item is assigned specific categories...I have some code that is returning the latest 5 images from the Media Library which looks like (in `footer.php`):

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'posts_per_page' => '5',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    query_posts($args);
?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h5><span>Recently</span> Added</h5>
            <ul>
                <?php
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    $url = get_attachment_link(get_post_thumbnail_id());
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_ID(), "thumbnail");
                ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"></a></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h5>Oops...</h5>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

What I'd like to do is only return the images if they have an assigned category.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

My code changed quite a bit...

Here is what the `functions.php` file looks like (which did not change):

```
function wptp_add_categories_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'wptp_add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

But here is the new code in `footer.php`, which returns the images from the Media Library, but only from an assigned category:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => '5',
        'category_name' => 'your-category-name'
    );
    $images = get_posts($args);
    if (!empty($images)) {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h5><span>Recently</span> Added</h5>
        <ul>
            <?php
                foreach ($images as $image) {
                    $attachment_link = get_attachment_link( $image->ID );
                    echo "<li><a href='".$attachment_link."'>".wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID)."</a></li>";
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h5>Oops...</h5>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I could have tweaked my existing code my adding `category_name => 'your-category-name'` to my `$args`, but this is a much more simplified approach and does the exact same thing...it just uses `get_posts` instead of `query_posts`.